# Code conversion issue from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to integrated this awesome Calender event library in my Kotlin project

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

I have created a Kotlin project. I am unable to convert the MonthChangeListener in Kotlin

```
MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener mMonthChangeListener = new MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        // Populate the week view with some events.
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = getEvents(newYear, newMonth);
        return events;
    }
};
```

I copied and pasted the Java code and pasted it into Kotlin project, here the code converted

```
val mMonthChangeListener = MonthChangeListener { newYear, newMonth -> // Populate the week view with some events.
    getEvents(newYear, newMonth)
}
```

Its throwing error

Without implementing this App crashes on start, here is the log

```
021-05-31 19:21:18.163 27099-27099/com.calendar.event101 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.calendar.event101, PID: 27099
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must provide a MonthChangeListener
        at com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView.getMoreEvents(WeekView.java:882)
        at com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView.drawHeaderRowAndEvents(WeekView.java:616)
        at com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView.onDraw(WeekView.java:488)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17185)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

[image]

Comment: On first sight it seems your problem is somewhere else. Java/Kotlin code above only creates a listener, it doesn't use it anywhere yet. Error says listener was not provided, so I guess in Java code you provided a `mMonthChangeListener` to the library and you didn't do this in Kotlin. Similar for the second problem: `getEvents()` seems to be some external method/function that you had in Java code, but you don't have it in Kotlin or it is inaccessible. What is this function? Where is it located in relation to above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 val monthChangeListener = MonthChangeListener { newYear, newMonth -> ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>() }
```

Regarding `getEvents` Actually, there is no such method `getEvents` at all in the library.

See the reply from the library owner

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/issues/436#issuecomment-302939156

You can find the sample to create the list by yourself using this sample of his.

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/blob/develop/sample/src/main/java/com/alamkanak/weekview/sample/BasicActivity.java

Comment: This worked, thank you for the direction. You are handler. :)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to create an instance of interface (i think it is an interface) can you please try to use anonymous class

```
val monthChangeListener : object = MonthChangeListener {}
```

it will want from you to implement members of this interface we use interface with this way in kotlin i hope i am right

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
val mMonthChangeListener:(Int,Int) -> List<WeekViewEvent> = MonthChangeListener { newYear, newMonth -> // Populate the week view with some events.
            return getEvents(newYear, newMonth)
        }
```

Comment: getting error ==> Unresolved reference: getEvents